# Can't run Google Chrome on Ubuntu 18/20

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, google-chrome

I've installed Ubuntu 20 LTS from official site with Rufus. And then I downloaded Google Chrome from google.com/chrome 64 bit.deb for Ubuntu
The first time I open, Chrome works nomally but after that time I can't manage to open it, I tried to launch it from terminal/gnome it yeilds:
`NaCl helper process running without a sandbox! Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly`
This also happens on Ubuntu 18.04
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Chrome works for me on all Ubuntu releases. You are doing something wrong. I hope you are not running it with sudo.

Comment: Chrome requires that you either add a PPA or manually install from a .deb package.  Neither are good methods to install software especially if you are not intimately familiar with package management in Ubuntu.  Have you tried to install and use Chromium instead?  It's essentially Chrome before Google adds all of the dirty proprietary mess.  Install w/: `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt install chromium-browser`

Comment: Read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269579/nacl-helper-process-running-without-a-sandbox-error-when-running-npm-tests

Comment: @Nmath yes, it works, chromium works on my machine.
However, I still can't manage to make gg chrome work on my machine although I've tried many ways but every time I open gg chrome it say "NaCl..."

Answer (score 0):

you can use Chromium browser (the open-source version of Chrome) instead of Google Chrome.

- You can run the command `chromium-browser` in terminal. Thank you.

Comment: Has to install chromium first before using that command.  Also not good answer for fixing chrome that the OP wants.

Comment: @crip659 Please check now. Thank you.

Comment: Command 'chromium-browser' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install chromium-browser.  Do have chrome installed.

Comment: @crip659 I agree with you. Regards.

Comment: Please also check another answer. Thank you.

Comment: Do think that chromium is installed on some other favours of ubuntu, but not Ubuntu itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111677/discussion-between-s-j-j-and-crip659).

Answer (score 0):

please try these commands.

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `wget --version` (checks whether wget is installed or not), if wget not installed, use the command `sudo apt install wget`
- `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
- `sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`
- For opening application via terminal, use `google-chrome`
  Thank you.

Attribution - https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_20-04_google_chrome_installation_guide/

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. After installing and from terminal I google-chrome but it yeilds "NaCl helper process....Most likely ... SUID"

Comment: @PhạmVănTiến, Hi, Try this command instead of the fifth above.                                                                              
                                                                                                                                             
                 sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: it does not work, still get NaCl...

Comment: @PhạmVănTiến, Hi, you can use chromium instead of chrome. Thank you.